# What is the proper way to use Python mock's autospec for objects's methods?

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing, mocking

I'm getting an error when trying to use `autospec=True` when mocking an object's method. I'll write down a simple example showing how to reproduce the error I'm getting. Suppose I have a very simple class like the following  one:

```
class SimpleClass:

    def target_method(self, a, b):
        return a + b
```

Now, in a different part of my system I have a function that interacts with a `SimpleClass` instance by doing `print(obj.target_method(a, b))` and I have to unitary test this function. I'd like to test it by mocking `target_method` with `autospec=True` to ensure the method signature and to check if it was called as expected. This when I get the error as described bellow:

```
In [24]: with patch.object(SimpleClass, 'target_method', autospec=True) as mock: 
    ...:     mock(2, 5) 
    ...:                                                                                                 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-24-04b2a0db8a31> in <module>
      1 with patch.object(SimpleClass, 'target_method', autospec=True) as mock:
----> 2     mock(2, 5)
      3 

<string> in target_method(*args, **kwargs)

/usr/lib/python3.6/unittest/mock.py in checksig(*args, **kwargs)
    169     func, sig = result
    170     def checksig(*args, **kwargs):
--> 171         sig.bind(*args, **kwargs)
    172     _copy_func_details(func, checksig)
    173 

/usr/lib/python3.6/inspect.py in bind(*args, **kwargs)
   2987         if the passed arguments can not be bound.
   2988         """
-> 2989         return args[0]._bind(args[1:], kwargs)
   2990 
   2991     def bind_partial(*args, **kwargs):

/usr/lib/python3.6/inspect.py in _bind(self, args, kwargs, partial)
   2902                             msg = 'missing a required argument: {arg!r}'
   2903                             msg = msg.format(arg=param.name)
-> 2904                             raise TypeError(msg) from None
   2905             else:
   2906                 # We have a positional argument to process

TypeError: missing a required argument: 'b'
```

If I'm getting it right, `mock` is executing itself as a stand-alone function and, by doing so, it requires the `self` parameter to be passed explicitly.

So, my question is if there is a way to use `autospec` when patching an object's method without getting this exception.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should call the method of the instantiated object:

```
with patch.object(SimpleClass, 'target_method', autospec=True): 
    obj = SimpleClass()
    obj.target_method(2, 5)
```

as described in https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.patch.object

Comment: Thank you! It worked for me and I'm not believing I did this simple mistake hehehe

I hope this answer can help other distracted developers in the future